# How to read an element content as string in XMLStreamReader2

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'm using `org.codehaus.stax2.XMLStreamReader2` from the Woodstox implementation of the [Stax2 API](https://github.com/FasterXML/stax2-api). I've elements like `<articleSummary>` that I'd like to read as text until , ignoring any XML/HTML inside them.

There is no `CDATA` wrapping for these elements, I could preprocess it and with text tools (e.g., sed) and add `CDATA`, but I wonder if I have some method to read them the way I said. I understand `getElementText()` or `getText( Writer, boolean)` are not good for this, is there any other method I'm missing?

Comment: You want to extract in a string all content of `<articleSummary>`? for example, from `<articleSummary><anotherTag>anotherValue</anotherTag></articleSummary>` to extract `<anotherTag>anotherValue</anotherTag>`? You have to implement your own method to do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051923/stax-xml-all-content-between-two-required-tags

Comment: Nice, thanks! If I get it right, that should work even for: <articleSummary>text mixed with <b>HTML</b> <i>tags</i>.</articleSummary>.